# Prevent page from be dragged left and right in mobile version

Tags: html, css

This [page](https://matteoboscolo.github.io/noircinema/eng/program.html) I'm working on has the following issue:

- when you are browsing through the mobile responsive mode (both from mobile device or Chrome's developer tools), you have the possibility to drag the page on the X axis, from the left to the right. This is not a desired effect since I just want the page to scroll on the Y axis.

I'm trying to prevent it with this, but no luck.

```
.body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Anyone can help?

Comment: Create a [MCVE]. In doing so you will probably find the problem yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace your css with :

```
.wrapgrid{
     overflow-x: hidden;
 }
```